# How to return plot from R function with the input name as its title

Tags: r

I was trying to get a plot from a r function,
so I wrote

> fn=function (inputdata) {......;output=...;return(hist(output))}

I want to get a histogram with a title of the input data, for example, if my inputdata is "abc", then I want the histogram to have a title of "abc".
I've tried to wrote

```
return(hist(output,main="inputdata"))
```

or

```
return(hist(output,main=inputdata))
```

but they are both wrong. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Alex Reynolds, it is partly a duplicate of a previous post. Based on the anwer found on this post:

```
set.seed(42)     
eytwaryt <- rnorm(1000)

foo <- function(x){ hist(x, main=deparse(substitute(x))) }
foo(eytwaryt)
```